# Advice on making a heating coil

Tags: circuit-analysis, electronic-load

I want to heat a pipe to 150 deg C. Pipe size aprox 0.5m long, diameter of 0.1m

My plan is to find a 240v to 24v adapter, connect this to some coiled nichrome wire (probably 24g) with a resistance of 12ohms.

Then wrap the nichrome coil around the pipe and insulate the pipe and coil.

I was also thinking of getting a PID temperature controller, where is the best place to connect the relay for this?

Also any ideas to electrically isolate the coil from the metal pipe?

Any comments and improvements would be appreciated

Thanks

Edit: So ill prob need more than one coil, so is it safe to connect the relay between the mains and multiple adapters?

Comment: I'd recommend kapton tape for insulation. Handles temperature and voltage well.

Comment: Heating something that size to 150C with only 48W? You'd better insulate it really well!

Comment: To expand on Brian's comment, you need to solve the thermal problem first. A pipe section that size at 150°C will dissipate quite a bit of _power_, which you need to supply with your coil to maintain the temperature; it becomes even harder if you intend to run liquid through it.

Comment: _I_ would try a bigger, variable heat source (say, the wire from a heated shower head coiled on Kapton, taking all precautions applicable to the higher voltage) and measure how much power is needed for the application, _then_ think of a controlled circuit. Play it safe and good luck.

Comment: Or for even more power such as if this tube will have anything in it, one or more heating elements from an electric hair dryer, clothes dryer, or hot water heater. Then of course, safety becomes important, as we're talking mains voltages and possibility of fire and electrocution.

Comment: So, buy a tube furnace.   When you don't need it anymore, sell it.   These are common laboratory items (but usually set at higher temperatures than 150C).

Answer (score 1):

A little pricey, perhaps, but take a look at this:

[image]